# How to send a ConverseRequest message by Converse using C++

Tags: c++, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am trying to build an google assistant client by using c++.
I've passed the authentication and created channel;
Then as the doc say: "Send a ConverseRequest message...", and stuck here, since Converse only has one parameter: ClientContext, 
How can a ConverseRequest convert to be ClientContext?

my code segment:

```
ConverseConfig config;
config.set_allocated_audio_in_config(&audio_in_config);
config.set_allocated_audio_out_config(&audio_out_config);

ConverseRequest request;
request.set_allocated_config(&config);

ClientContext context;
//context.AddMetadata(request.GetMetadata());

ConverseResponse *response  = stub_->Converse(&context);
```

Or some correct code sample will be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, C++ sample has offered:

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-cpp